# How would i create a shape out of the empty space that is intersected between two shapes?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, vector

So i need to create a shape from the empty space that i scratched in with two shapes created from the pen tool. I know it's messy but i'm just trying to figure out how to get this space before I make this picture. Thanks in advance everyone :D[image]

Comment: This question is incomplete, are those shapes traced, are they in the same layer or in different layers, do you want to color in between those shapes or do you want only the selection ?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm.. there are a few different options if you're in Photoshop, depending on what you're looking for.

*note: If you're just trying to color it in, you can select the "bucket" tool and fill paint between the two boundaries like so:*
[image]

If you want to create that individual shape, it depends if what you're drawing is all on one layer or separate layers, and what you're trying to do with it.

I think if you have two layers, start with step #1. If it's all on one layer, start with step # 2.

1. Merge the two layers (if they're on separate layers)*:
   [image]
2. Select the space between with the magic wand:
   [image]
3. Right Click, and "Make Layer via copy"
   [image]

Since you could be using this for many reasons, above may not be what you're looking for. There are many ways to approaching this, it just depends on what your end goal is.